# images in GitHub are not working on Readme

Tags: github, markdown

I recently tried to add some screenshots on my repository readme using the mark up

![](url for the picture)

and I couldn't get it the screenshot to show, I am very new to GitHub, I watched a couple videos but I can't find out why this is happening.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the url of your image?

Comment: Google [`how to add github readme image`](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=hwo+to+add+github+readme+image&oq=hwo+to+add+github+readme+image&aqs=chrome..69i57.5903j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I was editing the txt instead of the md now it's working fine. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out a repository and see how they did it.
For example check the repo [Material Dashboard](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard/) .
Now in the code section press the README.md file and open a `raw` view, ie. [README.md raw](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard/master/README.md).

You can see that they add png/images like so:
`[![Start page](assets/github/dashboard.png)]`
Note that you'll have to add a folder named `assets` and upload (or push) the images you want to show.

Comment: I found out I was trying to edit my own README.txt not the md, now I deleted the txt and edit the md with the mark up and it's showing fine!